Meaning of crazy of aspect in Joseph Conrad's The Secret Sharer
From the opening of Joseph Conrad's The Secret Sharer:
"On my right hand there were lines of fishing
stakes resembling a mysterious system of half-
submerged bamboo fences, incomprehensible in its
division of the domain of tropical fishes, and crazy of
aspect as if abandoned for ever by some nomad tribe of
fishermen now gone to the other end of the ocean; for
there was no sign of human habitation as far as the eye
could reach."
What does crazy of aspect mean here? Thanks.

I assumed your issue was with "of aspect". How the of works.

It means something like "very disorganized in appearance": the jumble of fishing stakes (pegs in the water used for fishing) looks misshapen and crooked, not regular and upright.
Aspect means "appearance to the eye or mind".
Crazy has various possible meanings, but there's a dated one, found in Dickens, meaning "full of cracks or flaws", also "crooked, askew". This seems more likely when applied to an object (it survives in the expression "crazy paving", meaning jumbled and irregular paving).
Either "in" or "of" is possible as a preposition to link them; I can find examples of both.

Aspect probably means "the positioning of a building or thing in a specified direction." rather than appearance.

Aspect: the positioning of a building or other structure in a particular direction.

+1. I do think Conrad could be drawing on the original sense of the word as irregularly zig-zag like the crazing on old ceramic glaze. The pattern of the stakes had a crazed appearance.

@ronaldchristenkkson It refers to the look of something. The way the bamboo fences were laid out.

crazy of aspect
It allows the author to follow the phrase with "as if" etc. and not have to use longer solutions like: it looked crazy, which would not fit the rest of the sentence.
It means: the aspect of which is crazy or in respect of aspect
Merriam Webster: the one below would fit here. You can look through the others, too.
b
: in respect to
slow of speech
Merriam Webster+of

Syntactically, it's the same format as saying someone is stocky of build or sound of mind. Or (my favourite so far! :) beady of eye.

@FumbleFingers Yeah, beady of eye is good. You needn't provide links to me. Since you are a native speaker I believe you and others should too. One can write new ones: rounded of belly.

Conrad has a more "literary" style than even most of his contemporaries, and it's certainly more grandiloquent than most current writers. I did manage to find one other written instance of crazy of aspect in Google Books, but I bet any money the writer there got it from Conrad (whether consciously or not). And it's a very dated / literary / "marked" construction - there are probably no contexts where a learner should prefer sound of mind over of sound mind. Learners should be made aware of that.
